# Issue running .NET 8 in Azure App Service running Linux

Tags: linux, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-linux

Just to prefix this with the fact that I have no Linux experience.

I have a .NET WebAPI that I publish to two local folder locations:

1. Windows

- Configuration = Release
- Target Framework = netcoreapp3.1 (I know, it's out of support)
- Deployment Mode: Self-contained
- Target Runtime : win-x64

2. Linux

- Configuration = Release
- Target Framework = netcoreapp3.1 (I know, it's out of support)
- Deployment Mode: Self-contained
- Target Runtime : linux-x64

I first create a Windows App Service (I'm familiar with these) and drop the first set of files into the wwwroot folder and everything works fine.

I then create a Linux App Service, and drop the second set of files into the wwwroot folder and it fails to start.

Going to the "Diagnose and solve problems" pane for the App Service I see it finds my start-up DLL but then says:

> Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support.

I download the full logs and the logs are all named "docker", but I'm not using a Docker container, so slightly mystified from the get-go.

If I go to the App Service's Advanced Tools and look at the Environment, I see it's using  Unix 5.15.131.1 and is 64 bit.

Not sure how to proceed...

UPDATE

This is the csproj file, minus project references to other projects in the Solution.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.1</AssemblyVersion>
        <FileVersion>1.0.0.1</FileVersion>
        <UserSecretsId>e593907e-90b3-4395-9cbc-5010001eb07c</UserSecretsId>
        <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
        <TypeScriptBuildMode>true</TypeScriptBuildMode>
        <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
        <!--<InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>-->
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount" Version="3.1.11" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="3.1.11" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.1.11" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices" Version="3.1.29" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="3.1.29" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.2">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.5.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="1.5.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.5.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Cors" Version="3.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.10.9" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="5.6.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="5.6.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="5.6.3" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!--  removed project references -->
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Please share your .csproj file and startup class

Comment: Add `<RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.Invariant" Value="true" />` to your `.csproj` and check once.

Comment: Add `InvariantGlobalization` in .csproj.`<PropertyGroup>
  <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
</PropertyGroup>`.Refer this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/globalization#invariant-mode)

Comment: @Harshitha - I added that (within an `<ItemGroup>` element) and republished but again, same error.

Comment: Delete the bin/obj folder in from KUDU => wwwroot directory.Redeploy the app again and check once

Comment: @Harshitha: I found references to a Window's Docker in the csproj.  This was added when the Proj was first created, but never used.  I removed it.  I now get `No usable version of libssl was found`.

Comment: Please share your csproj file I will try to run with your settings.

Comment: @Harshitha - details added, thanks in advance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256240/discussion-between-harshitha-and-drgriff).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a configured Web App with your configurations.

***Windows Deployment:***

Initially I have tried to deploy with `Target Runtime : win-x64`, but I got the below warning.

[image]

So, I have changed the Target Runtime to `win-x86` and deployed the App.

[image]

I am able to deploy and access the WebApp without any issues.

[image]

***Linux Deployment:***

I am able to deploy with Target Runtime `linux-x64` without any issues.

[image]

[image]

> Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support.

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/globalization#invariant-mode) ,to change the `Invariant` to true, we need to add the below line in `.csproj` file.

```cs
<PropertyGroup> <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization> </PropertyGroup>
```

> `No usable version of libssl was found`.

This type of error usually occurs in older .NET Core Version.

Thanks @[Davide](https://dev.to/n3wt0n/no-usable-version-of-the-libssl-was-found-solved-2ffa) for the clear steps.

The better approach is to upgrade to the latest version.

***OR***

If you are not willing to upgrade the version, Install the `OpenSSL` package from NuGet Packager Manager/run the command in KUDU Console.

[image]

> We tried to do a quick upgrade to .Net8.0, but were thwarted by incompatible NuGet packages

Yes, the packages which you have installed are not compatible with the newer `.Net8` version. You need to update the packages which are not supported.

[image]